# Render template on a per-action basis - Kohana3.2

Tags: php, templates, kohana, kohana-3

I'm currently using the default template system of Kohana. Currently, I extend for one of my controllers `Controller_Template_Default`. The output generated with this is perfect for most of my actions within this controller, however some actions have to output JSON, for which I need a blank page with solely the JSON data outputted on it (so no template).

I tried to return the JSON data without the template with `$this->response->body($data);` but it didn't work.

What is your advice? Should I render templates on a per-action basis instead of per-controller? And how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

In the before routine or in all "json" actions put the following sentence
this->auto_render = false;
With auto_render set to false, Kohana will not try to apply templates

Answer (score 0):

You should use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and provide a content-type header for the JSON response:

```
$this->response->headers('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$this->response->body(json_encode($data));
```

Furthermore, I render templates in my `after()` method with each action having his own content template within a global template. But to be able to easily switch between JSON and HTML, I find it better to use the Kostache module to separate logic from the actual template: https://github.com/zombor/KOstache

Read this article on how to use Kohana to supply different formats (JSON, HTML etc.): http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo json_encode($data);
die();
```

The script will stop executing after `die();` and you will have only `json_encode($data);` printed